# On the definition of the heat kernel of a generalized Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, heat-equation

I am currently reading the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540200628) and I don't quite understand the definition of the heat kernel, definition 2.15:

Given a Laplacian $H$, a family $p=(p_t)_{t\geq 0}$ of kernels is called a heat kernel if it "satisfies the heat equation $(\partial_t+H_x)p_t(x,y)$" (and some other requirements). But what exactly does it mean that $p$ solves the heat equation? Even if we fix $(t,y)$, then the function $p(t,{}\cdot{},y)$ is not an element of $\Gamma(M,E)$ and hence we can not apply $H$ to it. So how does the heat equation need to be understood in this case?

**Edit**: Here are two guesses of mine - is any of it correct?

- One idea would be that $(\partial_t+H_x)p=0$ is a shorthand for the following statement:
  \begin{equation}\tag{1}
  \forall y\in M:\forall v\in E_y:(\partial_t+H_x)p({}\cdot{},y)v=0
  \end{equation}
- Another idea would be to require
  \begin{equation}\tag{2}
  \forall\phi\in\Gamma(M,E):(\partial_t+H_x)P\phi=0,
  \end{equation}
  where
  $$(P\phi)(t,x)=(P_t\phi)(x)=\int_M p(t,x,y)\phi(y)|dy|$$
  and $y\mapsto|dy|$ is the Riemannian density.

Comment: It would be helpful if you maybe scan the book to see if $D_x$ is defined?

Comment: Maybe you could provide the definition of $D$?

Comment: Based on context I would guess it indicates the operator $H$ acting on the first argument by currying: if $F(x,y) = f(x)(y)$ then $(H_xF)(x,y) = (Hf)(x)(y)$.

Comment: In local coordinates on $M$, the operator $H$ is of the form $H = A^{ij}\partial^2_{ij}$, where each $A^{ij}$ is an endomorphism of the bundle $E$. The heat kernel $k_t$ at time $t$is a function of $M\times M$, so it's written as $k_t(x,y)$, where both $x$ and $y$ are in $M$. If you want to apply the differential operator $H$ to $k_t$, you have to specify which variable are you going to differentiate with respect to, $x$ or $y$. So you write $H_x$ to indicate that you want $H$ to differentiate with respect to $x$ and not $y$.

Comment: @Deane Sorry for bothering you - I know I already replied to your comment, but I think I did not a good job at explaining my problem. I understand that we can fix a coordinate $x$ or $y$, but then we obtain an endomorphism-valued section, whereas $H$ is defined on vector-valued sections. One idea would be to fix the coordinate $y$ **and** consider a fixed $v\in E_y$:$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+H_x\right)p_t(x,y)v=0$$

Comment: The equation makes sense, since $M\ni x\mapsto p_t(x,y)v\in E_x$ is in the domain of $H$, but I don't know if that's really the correct way to interpret the heat equation...

Comment: @Neal Please see my two comments above.

Answer (score 0):

> Fix $(t,y)\in\left]0,\infty\right[\times M$, then the function $x\mapsto p(t,x,y)$ is not an element of $\Gamma(M,E)$, so how does that $H$ act on it?

Indeed the function $p(t,{}\cdot{},y)$ is not an element of $\Gamma(M,E)$, but
\begin{equation}
p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\in\Gamma(M,E)\otimes E_y{}^*
\end{equation}
and we set $Hp(t,{}\cdot{},y)=(H\otimes\mathrm{id}_{E_y{}^*})p(t,{}\cdot{},y)$ (note the abuse of notation).

That being said, the authors mean that
$$\forall y\in M:(\partial_t+H_x)p({}\cdot{},y)=0.$$
(See proposition 4.2.14 in Nicolaescu's [notes on the Atiyah-Singer index theorem](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/ind-thm.pdf) for a confirmation.) This is equivalent to my first guess and in addition $(1)$ implies $(2)$ (see below for the proofs).

---

### Addendum

Proof 1: Let $e_1,\ldots,e_{\mathrm{dim}(E_y)}$ be a basis of $E_y$, then $p({}\cdot{},y)=\sum_ip({}\cdot{},y)(e_i)\otimes e^i$
and hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}p({}\cdot{},x,y)(t)+Hp(t,{}\cdot{},y)(x)=0\in L(E_y,E_x)
\end{equation}
is equivalent to
$$\sum_i\left\{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(p({}\cdot{},x,y)e_i)(t)+H(p(t,{}\cdot{},y)e_i)(x)\right\}\otimes e^i=0\in L(E_y,E_x)$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$\forall i:\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(p({}\cdot{},x,y)e_i)(t)+H(p(t,{}\cdot{},y)e_i)(x)=0\in E_x$$
and this is equivalent to
$$\forall v\in E_y:\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(p({}\cdot{},x,y)v)(t)+H(p(t,{}\cdot{},y)v)(x)=0\in E_x$$
Proof 2: Fix $\phi\in\Gamma(M,E)$ and $(t,x)\in\left]0,\infty\right[\times M$. Then
\begin{align}
&(\partial_t P\phi)(t,x)=&\\
&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left\{\int p({}\cdot{},x,y)\phi(y)|dy|\right\}=&\\
&=\int \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Big[p({}\cdot{},x,y)\phi(y)\Big](t)|dy|=&\\
&=\int -H\Big[p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\phi(y)\Big](x)|dy|=&\\
&=-H\bigg\{\underbrace{\int p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\phi(y)|dy|}_{=P_t\phi}\bigg\}(x)&
\end{align}
Here we used the fact that we can interchange differential operators and integration twice.

Comment: Note that$$\int \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Big[p({}\cdot{},x,y)\phi(y)\Big](t)|dy|=\int -H\Big[p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\phi(y)\Big](x)|dy|$$can be rewritten as$$\int \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Big[p({}\cdot{},x,y)\Big](t)\phi(y)|dy|=\int -H\Big[p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\Big](x)\phi(y)|dy|$$(i.e. we can pull out the $\phi$), but since this holds for all $\phi$, we get that the functions$$y\mapsto  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Big[p({}\cdot{},x,y)\Big](t)$$and$$y\mapsto -H\Big[p(t,{}\cdot{},y)\Big](x)$$ must be equal (I'd have to find the precise theorem we are using here) and since this holds true for all

Comment: $(t,x)$ I think that $(\partial_t+H)p=0$ and $\forall\phi:(\partial_t+H)(P\phi)=0$ are actually equivalent.